# How to get words from current visible page of ms word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I'm developing C# addin for MS Word. I can grab all words of current document - it's something like that:

```
app = (Word._Application )Application; // Application object comes on addin's connection
foreach(Word.Word word in app.Application.Words)
{
     doSmth(word);
}
```

My question, is how to grab all words not from entire document but from current active(visible for user) page?

In other words, I need to define active page/paragraph of app.Application.ActiveDocument and do something with "active" words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question. **[See update at end]**

Word's object model doesn't really have a "page" object, because the pagination of the document is constantly changing as you add and remove content (or change the font size, the paper size, etc.).  So, there is no "ActiveDocument.Pages(1)" sort of thing.

What's more, there's no easy way to tell what page is currently displayed. In part, that's because the user doesn't necessarily see only one page at a time. He may be viewing the end of one page and the start of the next, or several pages may be displayed - depending on his view settings.

If I can make the question slightly easier, then perhaps I can answer it in a way that helps you.  Let me re-define "current active (visible for user) page" as the page where the *selection* is.  (Actually, since the selection can span several pages, let's define it as "the page where the active end of the selection is").

I'll also answer using VBA because it's easier to play around with it in the VBA immediate window, and it's trivial to convert to C# when you need to (it's the same object model, after all).

Word's `Selection` object has the properties of a `Range`, and if you simply wanted all the selected words, then this would be trivial (`Selection.Words`!). However, if we want all the words on that *page*, then we need to work a little harder.

First, let's find out what page the (start of the) selection is on.  For this, we can use the Information method:

```
pageNumber = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

So now we know what page we're interested in.  We now need to get a `Range` object that includes all the text on that page.  We need to do this in two steps - by finding first the start and then the end of that range.

To find the start of the range, we can use the `Goto` function, which returns a Range object representing the start of a specified item:

```
startOfRange = ActiveDocument.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, pageNumber).Start
```

The end of the range is either the start of the next page (minus one character, but let's not quibble), or the end of the document (if we're on the last page):

```
If pageNumber = ActiveDocument.Content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
    endOfRange = ActiveDocument.Content.End
Else
    endOfRange = ActiveDocument.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, pageNumber + 1).Start
End If
```

Now we can construct a `Range` object encompassing all the text on the page:

```
Set pageRange = ActiveDocument.Range(startOfRange, endOfRange)
```

... and from there we can get the words:

```
Set words = pageRange.Words
```

Here is a short VBA macro that uses the above technique to report the number of words on the active page:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim pageNumber As Integer
    Dim startOfRange As Integer
    Dim endOfRange As Integer
    Dim pageRange As Range

    pageNumber = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)

    startOfRange = ActiveDocument.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, pageNumber).Start

    If pageNumber = ActiveDocument.Content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument) Then
        endOfRange = ActiveDocument.Content.End
    Else
        endOfRange = ActiveDocument.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, WdGoToDirection.wdGoToAbsolute, pageNumber + 1).Start
    End If

    Set pageRange = ActiveDocument.Range(startOfRange, endOfRange)

    MsgBox pageRange.Words.Count

End Sub
```

---

**UPDATE**
OK, it turns out that there's a much easier way to do this.  Word has a "special bookmark" that points to the text on the current page, so this will do the same as all that code above:

```
words = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Words
```

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me. Only one remark - in C# accesing words of "page" bookmark looks like  
'Application.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.get_Item("\\Page").Range.Words'.

Comment: You should be able to avoid the `get_Item` methods if you're using an up-to-date version of C#/.NET, and just say `Bookmarks[@"\page"]`.